# Discrete Mathematics - Modular arithmethics

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I've been trying to solve a task for some while now but I'm currently very stuck.

> For the integers $a$ and $b$ it applies that $b \equiv a \pmod{91}$ and $\gcd (a, 91) = 1$. Determine a positive number $k> 1$ such that $b^k \equiv a \pmod{91}.$

I know that  $b^{\phi(91)} = 1\pmod{91}$ and  $b^{\phi(91)} = 72$.

After this I'm pretty empty. Would anyone be so kind to guide me or help me in the right direction?

Comment: what is sgd? another name for gcd?

Comment: So $k=\varphi(91)+1$ would do it, right?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What  is `sgd`? The gcd?

Comment: Hello guys, sorry for the translate error. SGD is biggest common divider!

Comment: $\phi(91)=72$  not $b^{\phi(91}$

Comment: @gt6989b Hey, its exactly what it is, greatest common divisor, I used google translate and I forgot that part, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Raffaele yeah thats what I ment, its correct right?

Comment: Do you mean like $27^3\equiv 27\mod 91;\;64^3\equiv 64\mod 91;\;90^3\equiv 90\mod 91$

Comment: @Raffaele To be honest at this point im not even sure what im looking for myself.

Comment: @abiessu why is it +1?

Comment: @Rocky abiessu means that $a^{73}\equiv a \mod 91$ for any $0\le a\le 90$. The reason of $+1$ should be quite clear, since $a^{\phi(91)}\equiv 1 \mod 91$.

Comment: @Raffaele Thanks alot, I get it a little more now. But im supposed to find the value between 0 and 90 then?

Comment: @Raffaele could you assist me some moer on this task? Im not so sure what I should focus on trying to do.

Comment: @Raffaele Hello, I have been more succesful in coming forward but I still doesnt realise why we add the +1. Its not very obvious im sad to say. I understand why we take Eulerphi and that it is 72 but the +1 doesnt make sense to me.

Comment: @abiessu Why do we take +1? What is the formula for that?

Comment: Please consider my answer.  Does it help clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Since we have $a\equiv b\mod 91$ and also $\varphi(91)=72$ added to $(a,91)=(b,91)=1$ giving $b^{72}\equiv 1\mod 91,$ then we can say $b\cdot b^{72}\equiv b\cdot 1\equiv a\equiv b^{73}\mod 91$.

Thus $b^k\equiv a\mod 91$ using $k=\varphi(91)+1$.

Answer (score 0):

$k$ calculate as discrete logarithm by modulo $91$ and have form $k=r\pmod{m}$, where $r$=`2..11` and $m$=`3,4,6,12`.

gp-code:

```
k91()=
{
 K= [];
 for(a=0, 90, if(gcd(a,91)==1, for(b=0, 90, if(gcd(b,91)==1,
  m= Mod(b, 91);
  h= znorder(m);
  k= znlog(a, m, h);
  if(k, if(k>1,
   K= concat(K, [[k,h]]);
  ))
 ))));
 print(vecsort(K,,8))
};
```

Output `[r,m]`:

```
[[2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 6], [2, 12], [3, 4], [3, 6], [3, 12], [4, 6], [4, 12], [5, 6], [5, 12], [6, 12], [7, 12], [8, 12], [9, 12], [10, 12], [11, 12]]
```